# Making Visual Studio 2019 a Fortran IDE (with gfortran)

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, gfortran

I would like to know how I can tune **Visual Studio 2019** to have a fully featured modern Fortran IDE for **gfortran**.

This would include:

- one click compilation
- debuging
- auto-completion

If you also known any other interesting feature I would be interested.

Many thanks.

Comment: Would that be on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Windows 10 in my case.